# Estimating/Reconstructing the distance matrix by given pairwise distance of a subset of points

Tags: metric-spaces

Given a set of points $X$ which separated into two subsets $X_1$ and $X_2$

i.e. $X_1 \cup X_2 = X$ and $X_1 \cap X_2 = \emptyset$

We have the pairwise distance matrix $M^1$,$M^2$ of set $X_1$, $X_2$ respectively

i.e. $M^1_{ij} = d(x_i,x_j)$ where $x_i,x_j \in X_1$ and $M^2_{ij} = d(x_i,x_j)$ where $x_i,x_j \in X_2$

Combine some distances across the two sets (only distances of a few combinations exist) $d(x_i,x_j)$ where $x_i\in X_1$ and $x_j\in X_2$

How can one reconstruct the pairwise distance matrix of set $X$ within a tolerance of error?